# Failed to find the transpiler exported from @dataform/core. Ensure packages are installed and upgrade to a recent version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform

I am following the quicktart example from the google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/quickstart)  but when I try to execute the workflow, I can't click on the `Start execution` button. I have an error in the right panel which tells me :

`Failed to find the transpiler exported from @dataform/core. Ensure packages are installed and upgrade to a recent version.`

I tried to add a `package.json` file like following :

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@dataform/core": "1.6.2"
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Anyone have an idea of the issue ?

EDIT : Here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you ensured that you have `initialized the workspace` and also have `committed` the changes you made?

Comment: Yes! I commited the changes and the workspace is up to date, but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the disabled `Start Execution` button? Also screenshot of the error message where it is appearing?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Non of the sqlx appears in the action drop down list.

Answer (score 3):

Try to go to the packages.json file and then push the "Install packages" button. (See the screenshot)

[Install packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOGhW.png)

It worked for me this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using the web console doesn't work for me as well. For now the workaround that works for me is to develop locally via dataform core.

Comment: I think the problem could be the payment method. As i work in a company, it is linked and manage by the organization. In the quickstart tutorial, It is demanded to check if the billing API is enabled and if the payment overview page is accessible.
In my case, i have the Billing API enabled but the payment page is not accessible..

Answer (score 0):

Premisse: Your workspace is connected to some git external repository.

Do this steps:

- Delete your workspace;
- Edit outside of workspace, using your IDE or cloud shell. Confirm if project_id is correct in dataform.json, if not fix. Confirm if your source is referenced the corrects the the project-ids and dataset names. If not, fix. Commit and push;
- Re-create the workspace again;
- Run the workflow